# Why does my minecraft craft bukkit doesn't work?

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

i am trying to code minecraft plugin on eclipse. No errors, warnings, loads up on minecraft, but doesn't do anything. Can you please help me ?
Here is my code:

```
 package me.me.me;

    import org.bukkit.ChatColor;

import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.block.Block;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.block.Action;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerInteractEvent;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class main extends JavaPlugin implements Listener {
    
    @EventHandler
    public void onInteract(PlayerInteractEvent event) {
        Action action = event.getAction();
        Player player = event.getPlayer();
        Block block = event.getClickedBlock();
        
        if(action.equals(Action.LEFT_CLICK_BLOCK)) {
        if(block.getType().equals(Material.EMERALD_BLOCK)) {
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "emerald");
             if(player.getHealth() != 20){
                 if (player.getHealth() > 19) {
                 player.setHealth(20);
                    }
            }
        }
}
}
}
```

Comment: have you checked the server logs?

Comment: Yes i have. it says that my plugin is enabled but doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this code everything what you done? Remember you need to override `onEnable` method to do something on plugin load and event listener must be registered.

```
@Override
public void onEnable() {
    this.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, this);
}
```